# Call a function from inside on()

Tags: jquery

I need to call a function from the `on()` handler. In my example code I must call `func1()`. I use `on()` as `#myid` does not exist on load of the document. Here is the code:

```
func1: function (e, data) {
  console.log('func1');
  this.func3();
},
func2: function (e, data) {
  $('#myid').on('click', function () {
    this.func1();
  });
}
},
```

This code does not work. The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.func1() is not a function

How do I call a function from inside the `on()`?

Comment: Simply call `func1()`. without this.

Comment: Is `func1` and `func2` part of a object? Share the relevant code

Comment: `this.func3();`  need to be `func3();`  and `this.func1();`  need to be `func1();`

Comment: @AlivetoDie, if op has defined like `var obj  {func1: {}, func2: {}}` then it will not work

Comment: yogen darji, without this. I get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: func1() is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that these are properties of an object, your issue is because `this` within the click handler will refer to the `#myId` element, not the parent object. To fix this you need to cache the `this` reference in a variable.

Also note that you state you are using `on()` because the `#myId` element doesn't exist on load of the page. If that's the case you need to use the delegated signature for the `on()` method, which you're currently not doing. Try this:

```
var obj = {
  func1: function (e, data) {
    console.log('func1');
    this.func3();
  },
  func2: function (e, data) {
    var _this = this; // note this variable...

    $(document).on('click', '#myid', function() {
        _this.func1(); // ...and it's use here
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: It would too, although that structure is an assumption on my part.

Comment: Even I am assuming the same

Comment: @Linda glad to help. Also note that I updated the answer to give you the correct usage for `on()` when delegating events - your current code wouldn't work in that regard

Answer (score 5):

> Uncaught TypeError: this.func1() is not a function

You will encounter this error, because the context of `this` here is different. It points to context of jQuery's element `#myid`, instead of the original. To get rid of it, try this:

```
// ... Code removed for brevity

func2: function (e, data) {
         var self = this;

         $('#myid').on('click', function () {
           self.func1();
         });
       }

// ... Code removed for brevity
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Now I see why it did not work.